# Form Value update using Angular js, Node Js , express js and Mongo DB

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm totally new to MEAN and working on demo project where I can perform basic CRUD activity using Nodejs,Express, Angular js and Mongo DB but facing  issue during update.

I don't know how to call Mongo DB update query using Angular js ng-click. I can fetch data from Mongo DB which is showing in the screenshot below.

But I want to update the values if user make any change in the values and press submit. I'm using ng-click for update.

I'm trying it for last two days but not able to find any solution, I've checked few example but find it they have different approach .

Any help will be appreciated

Html View :

[image]

HTML View Code :

```
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" id="id-form" ng-app="app-setting" ng-controller="SettingController" >
    <tbody><tr>

        <th valign="top">Facebook Link:</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="inp-form" ng-model="settings.facebook"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th valign="top">Twitter Link:</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="inp-form" ng-model="settings.twitter"></td>

    </tr>


    <tr>
        <th valign="top">Google+:</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="inp-form" ng-model="settings.googleplus"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

        <tr>
        <th valign="top">Youtube:</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="inp-form"  ng-model="settings.youtube"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

            <tr>
        <th valign="top">Email:</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="inp-form" ng-model="settings.email"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

            <tr>
        <th valign="top">Contact #:</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="inp-form" ng-model="settings.contactnumber"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>




<tr>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <td valign="top">
        <input type="submit" class="form-submit" value="update" ng-click="update(settings)">

    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
<!-- end id-form  -->
```

Controller :

```
.module('app-setting')
.controller('SettingController',SettingController);

function SettingController($scope, $http ) {
 $scope.page = "Setting";

 $http.get('/admin/get-setting-list')
  .then(function(res){
      $scope.settings = res.data;  

    });


   $scope.update = function(data){
     //what will be here 

 };
```

Routes :

```
 var Setting = require('../models/setting').Setting;

 router.put('/admin/setting/:id', function(req, res, next) {
 Setting.findAndModify(req.params.id,req.body, function (err, post)  {
 if (err) return next(err);
  user:res.json(post);
 });
```

});

Model :

```
     var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var adminService = new Schema({
  facebook: String,
  youtube: String,
  googleplus:  String,
  twitter:String,
  email:String,
  contactnumber:String,
  created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

var Setting = mongoose.model('Setting', adminService);

module.exports = {
  Setting : Setting
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your HTML calls update method and passes settings object to it, which looks ok in angular controller.

By looking at your node.js code, you need to call

$http.put('/admin/setting/:id',....) in settingController

ref:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

and you need to understand http methods
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: Thanks for reply, Can you please confirm how i can pass form values along with id so that it can be Handel in my route, I have written `
       $scope.update = function(user){
      var id= user._id;
      $http.put('/admin/setting/:'+id,user) ;
      
      };
     `   But it is not working

Comment: //for id u need to have some unique field , either try to generate a unique key at client end or mongo gives a default document id.

However in ur case u can use contact num as unique
`
$scope.update = function(data){

$http.post('/admin/setting/:'+data. contactnumber, data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);

 };

Comment: Yes, I have written this   `$scope.update = function(data){ var id= data._id; $http.put('/admin/setting/:'+id,data) ; };` But it is not working, can you please suggest i have passed id and Form data correctly or missing something

Comment: hey , ur data is nothing but settings json coming from html , and i don't see settings having a _id key , so ya it's wrong
try console.log(id);
and y a downvote man ?

Comment: Thanks for Help Bro, One more thing, Now i can pass value but getting 404 for URl **admin/setting/:561b61e96abd5c1a1011e8bb**  , error is "app.use.res.render.message (/home/ubuntu/workspace/app.js:93:13)" , I understand the i have to write app.use , which i have define like  `app.use('/admin/setting/:id',setting);` this but it is not working

Comment: :561b61e96abd5c1a1011e8bb must be 561b61e96abd5c1a1011e8bb,
colons ain't needed and have a look at example code https://github.com/aishwat/flowAppServer
u need app.put() not app.use()

Comment: Thanks Bro , Now i can edit my record, One more issue which i have faced related to ObjectId which i have solved by using `var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id);`